# SQL Server File Attaching Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

I am attaching DBs using SQL Server 2005 Express.  Some files are attaching with path and some without it (see below)

[image]

I am attaching them all from the same folder. Please advise what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any difference except how you named the file when you restored/attached the database. I think it is the `Attach As` field you need to change when attaching and `Destination > Database` field when restoring.